# Different use of scope operator

Tags: c++, scope

To transform a string and make it lowercase, we might do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str("Sample STRING");

    cout << str << endl;

    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know what `std::transform` is all about; but what's the scope operator `::` doing in front of the function `tolower`?

If I remove the scope operator then the compiler complains of a function mismatch. If I add `std` in front of the `::` operator then the compiler also complains of a function mismatch. What is the purpose of the scope operator in front of `tolower`? I don't know what it's called, and I searched everywhere for an explanation but to no avail.

Comment: The operator is called the scope resolution operator. When there's nothing to the left, it's called the unary scope operator. (Section [basic.lookup.qual] in the C++ standard)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You should `#include <algorithm>` to use `std::transform`.
2. The `tolower` function you want is defined in `ctype.h` or `cctype`. You should include one of these headers. The former declares `tolower` in the global namespace; the latter declares it in the `std` namespace.
3. It's likely that without the `::`, you're picking up the function template `std::tolower` declared in the `<locale>` header. Of course, this only happens because you have `using namespace std;`. This is a particular example of how `using namespace std;` can be dangerous.
4. The `::` with nothing on the left means the name to the right will be "looked up in global scope" and will find the global `tolower` rather than `std::tolower`. (Therefore, you should `#include <ctype.h>` to make sure you get the global declaration.)

Answer (score 5):

`::` without a left side bypasses looking in all accessible sub-scopes and forces the use of the root (or global) scope.

Comment: But why would you want to look in global scope when you simply just don't use a namespace?

Comment: Mostly when you have shadowed a name in your current namespace. In in your example I have no idea why one would use `::tolower(int)` over `std::tolower(int)`. Both should be the same.

Comment: Apparently not, using `std::tolower` causes an error. You could try out the code with the modifications yourself.